# Sonar test coverage sensor being ran on Pull Request only

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have a jenkins multi-pipeline project setup doing sonar scans with PR decoration.

When a pull request is scanned sonar correctly runs the test coverage report sensor and coverage is reported correctly.

However when this is merged back to our main the sensor just isn't being ran.

PR Branch:

```
....
INFO: Importing 34 Roslyn reports
INFO: Sensor C# [csharp] (done) | time=8804ms
INFO: Sensor C# Tests Coverage Report Import [csharp]
INFO: Parsing the OpenCover report C:\Jenkins\workspace\Build-API_PR-273\.\Tests\SharedDataServices.Tests\coverage.opencover.xml
....
```

Main Branch:

```
....
INFO: Importing 34 Roslyn reports
INFO: Sensor C# [csharp] (done) | time=13859ms
INFO: Sensor JavaSecuritySensor [security]
....
```

As you can see it completely omits the sensor.

Things I've checked:

- Pull request works and coverage is being reported fine
- The reports are being generated in the same relative locations on Main
- The contents of the reports are not empty
- The contents of the reports refer correctly to the tested .cs files

Any ideas or tips please?

Comment: how does your pullrequest analysis look like, are you already on 8.3 using the sonarqube integrated detection, or a custom one. Which scanner are you using? eg. in our project we had the issues that our sonarqube target sometimes was executed, before the testcoverage was computed, can this be a reason. Hard to tell based on the logs.

Comment: I'm on sonar 8.1.0.31237 mainly using the C# sensor but it's always been automatic I'm not sure what actually triggers these

Comment: Raised with sonar https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-dotnet/issues/3347#issue-618865716